# Are there supposed to be bionic addicts in The Den?

Tags: fallout-2

I'm playing the Steam version of Fallout 2 with the v1.02.28 Unofficial Patch, High Resolution Patch and Restoration Project 2.3.3.

I'm wandering from place to place in The Den, selecting a destination far enough away that I can't see my character, when suddenly the game goes into combat mode, and I'm under attack. I go look and see that one of the usually-harmless addicts is attacking me with his bare hands. Not only that, but he attacks six times per turn! I smack him back, and he starts running away - at about 30 or so hexes per turn! I try to chase him, and notice often it gives me two turns in a row, but still, this guy is at least three times faster than anything I've seen in the game.

My character has max action points for a PC which is 10, so with the turn-based movement and attacks using AP, I either need to luck out, or get my ally to spread out and luck out, to catch him, since he can even run out of bullet range in one turn.

Is this supposed to happen, or is this a bug?

Comment: I played F2 long long time ago and I remember some kind of weirdness in the area. Not sure, if it's something you've described, or something else. I remember staying away of fighting addicts in Den, because of some reason.

Comment: Ya the other thing about the Den is that it animated the movement of each civilian too, one at a time... so when some other NPCs started shooting guns and a crowd of people started running, it took a long time to get to the next turn.

Comment: Looks like that's it, I hated to fight in Den. It's pretty buggy compared to other locations, in my opinion.

Comment: The guy attacking you is likely high on Jet. Jet gives you bonus action points. Drugs mess with your head. That's likely what's going on; he's tripping balls, and Jet gives him 'wings' and allows him to move really really fast. Getting double turns is likely because he is too far away from you at the end of your first turn to perceive you as an active threat, and so he skips a turn (allowing you to go twice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max AP is 14 (15 with a cookie; 19 with both Bonus Moves) if you do jet and take both Action Boy perks.

My advice is to use a laser rifle (45 range) and don't let him kite you: kite him (if he runs, so do you -the other way-  and wait for him).

**Both of your sequences may be the same**, which could flip-flop who gets two turns in a row. An NPC with 10 AP and bonus move would seem to run ~30 hex per turn and be able to attack you three times, twice.

Perception is very important. Other than its related perks, sequence is entirely based on PE. At the next opportunity, take PE +1 (the Earlier Sequence perk is only good if you have 10 PE already).

Comment: Aha, I bet that's what it is. I'm currently learning the hard way not to get addicted to stuff and to watch what I eat - I'm in recovery from booze and Rad-away, so my perception tanked a bit, and it occurred to me he could be on something making him hyper. I didn't know I could get my AP over 10 without drugs... hmm... Thanks!

Comment: @Dronz, Rest for seven days: [Addiction](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Addiction).

Comment: Thank you! Yep time to sleep it off! I was doing that, and suddenly got a stream of +1 radiation alerts... I thought maybe I was in a fallout zone, but then I figured out it was the fruit I had eaten earlier. Fallout 2 has some cool stuff in it.

Comment: @Dronz, Once you've beaten it a few times come join us: [Fonline](http://www.fonline-reloaded.net/). Be aware though, *the wasteland is harsh*.